# Multi-line Text formatting on a Chart's bar value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, kendo-ui

Is it possible to format multiline text on series values labels for a stacked bar chart.

The image below is what I am after.

The things I have tried so far.

1. Add a table to the report with column groups for each grade. Each column group will have ten detail columns so I can draw the pesky arrow lines, actually two groups of ten, one for the line and one for the arrows. That would equate to 12 x 20 textboxes to support stupid arrows.
2. Row group by grade a place a chart in each group detail. This is fine and then I can play with the horizontal axis offsets and get an almost identical match, however, **I need to have two rows of text per value on the chart, is this possible?**

[image]

I am open for other options. I might attempt to migrate this over to a kendo chart as I have converted a few chart reports that are impossible to render on the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to format multiline text on series values labels for a
>   stacked bar chart.

Yes, it is possible. You can use `Environment.NewLine` to produce a new line in any SSRS expression.

Even you can use it in the stacked bar chart series label, just concatenate the value you want to show with the produced new line.

```
=Fields!FirstLineValue.Value & Environment.NewLine & Fields!SecondLineValue.Value
```

It should produce:

[image]

Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: Doh! - Great solution.